# Load controller dynamically without routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

so i have my index.html like following

```
<html>
    <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <div id="main" ng-include="body"/>
        <div id="sidebar" ng-include="side"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.gotoXXX() {
        $scope.sidebar="xxx.html";
    }
}]);
```

sidebar.html:

```
<script src="XXXcontroller.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="XXXcontroller">
</div>
```

Obviously, this is not working. It prompts for XXXcontroller not defined. So I figured the controller was not properly injected. And I need to change view partially, so routeProvider is not an option.

So I'm wondering, Is there anyway to dyanmically inject controllers?

Comment: If you are loading correctly the script file for `XXXcontroller.js` the controller will automatically gets injected as defined..what is the problem then ?

Comment: No dynamic loading of Angular artifacts is not supported by default in Angular. Look at oclazyload and angularamd projects to see if they fit your bill.